# Getter Setter en dart

Tags: dart

Tengo el siguiente Getter y Setter:

```
class Categoria {

  String categoria;

   String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
   }

    void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
  }
```

Al momento de generar el String del Setter va perfecto:

```
import 'package:vivi_carhue/entidades/direcciones.dart' as dire;

onTap: () {
          dire.Categoria().setCategoria("supermercado");
          //String cate = "supermercado";
          //dire.categoria(cate);
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pantalla_lista(),
             ),
          );
```

El problema lo tengo en el Getter, ya que me sale error:

```
  final response =
  await http.get( dire.direcciones.ip.toString() +  dire.Categoria.getCategoria().toString() );
```

> "Instance member 'getCategoria' can't be accessed using static access"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás accediendo al método `getCategoria()` asumiendo que ese método es `static`, pero no lo es, tienes 2 opciones:

1- declarar tu método static

2- Usa la instancia de Categoria en lugar de la clase

Así:

```
 dire.Categoria().getCategoria().toString()
```

Comment: Y por que el metodo Setter me devuelve siempre null ????

Comment: dire.Categoria().setCategoria("supermercado");
          print(dire.Categoria().getCategoria());

Comment: Pues porque estas usando instancias distintas , cada vez que haces: Categoria()  , es una nueva instancia (un nuevo objeto).  Si por ejemplo, antes declaras ,  final cat = dire.Categoria();  cat.setCategoria("X");   print( cat.getCategoria()); ,  vas a ver el resultado :) .  Revisa conceptos de programación orientada a objetos.

Comment: Una ultima diego y no te molesto mas. Si yo tengo el setter en una clase botones, y el getter en la clase Negocio. Como podrehacer para compartir la misma instancia

Comment: Serán instancias diferentes porque pertenecen a distintas clases,  por eso te recomiendo que leas más sobre programación orientada a objetos para que entiendas esos conceptos.

Comment: gracias diego, graciasss